# How do I make discord bot display Typing and stop typing when a message is sent

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want my discord bot to show the Typing message when he's typing, and when he sends a message, he stops typing. async with message.channel.typing doesn't seems to work, cause the bot continues to type even after the message is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Context.trigger_typing` method:

```py
@bot.command()
async def send_typing(ctx):
    await ctx.trigger_typing()
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await ctx.send('End of typing')
```

#### Reference:

- [`Context.trigger_typing`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=trigger_typing#discord.ext.commands.Context.trigger_typing)